# How To exclude helper objects from intersection check by raycaster in threejs?

Tags: three.js, helper, intersection, scene, raycasting

I have a threejs scene with intersection checking on objects. I'm adding every scene object to the array which is then checked by the raycaster.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
```

I then check the color of an object and change it on contact with the mouse pointer.

```
INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( 0xff0000 );
```

If I add a helper object, like `CameraHelper` or `GridHelper`, to the scene I get constant errors because `.getHex` `.setHex` is not possible with the helper objects.

Is it possible to exclude the helper objects from this check and how would I do this?

It has to be something like `scene.children` - scene.helpers but I cannot come up with a way to do this.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create an array of objects that you want `Raycaster` to process.

```
var objects = [];

objects.push( mesh1 );
objects.push( mesh2 );

---

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects, recursiveFlag );
```

three.js r.73

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the objects to the scene and an extra array as you described and only process the extra array in the raycaster.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, there are 2 solutions:

- https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group
- https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Layers

A reason you might not want to use Group for this is because you might be using Group to keep multiple objects together but you would only want to raycast test for some objects in the Group.